# WIFI card intel ax210 bluetooth not working properly

Tags: drivers

I have kernel 5.10+.
Not sure if driver is up to date, how to install the latest?
Help!

Comment: What Ubuntu product & release are you using?  *We don't know what you're using, with kernel stack options existing for Ubuntu LTS releases & your kernel stack chosen by the ISO used to install; thus don't know the starting point to assist you*

Comment: Where did you get this kernel 5.10+ from?